# Connecting FileZilla to SFTP, OpenSSH

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, openssh, filezilla

I've a Ubuntu machine where is installed OpenSSH.

I want upload/download files there thru SFTP with FileZilla.

SSH works good with putty etc, but when I try to connect with FileZilla, I get

```
Status: Connecting to A.B.C.D...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "user@A.B.C.D" 22
Command:    Pass: ****
Status: Connected to A.B.C.D...
Error:  Out of memory!
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Here's about it

> http://www.snailbook.com/faq/sftp-corruption.auto.html

but I didn't understood how to fix it or what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably caused by one of your login scripts on the Ubuntu machine that is generating output to places it should never output to. (It's like using the sink instead of the bathroom... I bet your room mate will run out of <del>memory</del> tolerance pretty soon.) PuTTY has a FAQ section about it. Read it [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-outofmem2).

Summary:

> #### A.7.6 When attempting a file transfer, either PSCP or PSFTP says ‘Out of memory’ and dies.
>
> This is almost always caused by your
> login scripts on the server generating
> output. PSCP or PSFTP will receive
> that output when they were expecting
> to see the start of a file transfer
> protocol, and they will attempt to
> interpret the output as file-transfer
> protocol. This will usually lead to an
> ‘out of memory’ error for much the
> same reasons as given in question
> A.7.5.
>
> This is a setup problem in your
> account on your server, not a
> PSCP/PSFTP bug. Your login scripts
> should never generate output during
> non-interactive sessions; secure file
> transfer is not the only form of
> remote access that will break if they
> do.
>
> On Unix, a simple fix is to ensure
> that all the parts of your login
> script that might generate output are
> in .profile (if you use a Bourne shell
> derivative) or .login (if you use a C
> shell). Putting them in more general
> files such as .bashrc or .cshrc is
> liable to lead to problems.

Comment: One other solution is to pipe the output of any commands in your .bashrc to /dev/null.